# Accessing and displaying related records from multiple tables in Web2py

Tags: mysql, web2py

I have 3 tables defined:

```
db.define_table('image',
Field('title', unique=True,length=200),
Field('file', 'upload'),
format = '%(title)s')

db.define_table('author',
Field('name', unique=True,length=100),
Field('type'),
format = '%(name)s')

db.define_table('post',
Field('image_id', 'reference image'),
Field('author_id', 'reference author'),
Field('email'),
Field('body', 'text'))
```

I seem to be able to access the "posts" table as follows

```
dbref=db
qry=''
fields=['body','image_id']
sel=[db.post[field] for field in fields] 
posts=dbref(qry).select(*sel)
```

However I need to get the related record in the table "image", and display the image and the text on a web page. How do I do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there aren't many records, you can use a recursive select:

```
{{for post in posts:}}
{{=IMG(_src=URL('default', 'download', args=post.image_id.file))}}
...
{{pass}}
```

`post.image_id.file` will result in an additional select for each post in order to retrieve the file name. If there are many records, it will instead be more efficient to do a join:

```
posts = db((db.post.image_id == db.image.id) & qry).select(*sel)
```

Then in the view:

```
{{=IMG(_src=URL('default', 'download', args=post.image.file))}}
```

Actually, it is common to name reference fields the same as the table to which they refer (rather than appending "_id"). For example:

```
Field('image', 'reference image')
```

In that case, the code in the view would be `post.image.file` whether using a join or a recursive select -- so you could change the method used in the controller without needing to change the view code.